# Can I create an automated approval workflow for other people in the organisation & email notification does not have my name?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, document-library, power-automate, sharepoint-permissions

[image]I am new to sharepoint!

I have been given a task to create automated document approval workflow for Person A & Person B. So if Person A uploads a document on a folder Person B will be notified with the email notification to approve/reject.

So I have created workflow using my account but whenever Person A uploads the document the email notification is going with my name. How can I do the changes that email notification can go on Person A name.(without using Person A login credentials)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Outlook connector, you can send an email as if it came from a shared mailbox. So you need to create a shared mailbox first and on the shared mailbox properties make sure to add your account to send as the mailbox.

Another way is to use the Mail connector which will allow you to send emails from microsoft@powerapps.com and not your email. For more info, watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvNMGsyWooM

Comment: Is there anyway I can remove Created By field in the email notification generated.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to go on document library in whic is the document you want to be approved and go to (...)-> Automate->Power automate-->Create a flow. From there you can choose several type of prebuilt flows (you are able to change delete some aprts obviously).

I try this and the email is notified as "Microsoft Power Apps & Power Automate".
Make a try on your private and if it is ok put on Production.

tell me if you can solve.
Lorenzo